# Get the data from Github Action Artifacts

Tags: typescript, github-actions, github-pages

I have an Artifact, that is atached to an Github Action. The Artifacts just stores one .json file with some data. Is it possible, to get the json file TypeScript with an http request? Because I have an Angular site, stored on github pages, which needs the data from that Json file.

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/artifacts?

Comment: okay ive tried it. I mean I can donalod the ziped json file with the api, but i want to make a get request, where I get just the Json, which is atached on the artifacts, without downloading the ziped json.